# WP7: "The app could not be launched for debugging", different from the usual

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-phone-7

I have joined the legions of people getting the error "The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."

My symptoms are different from usual, and the usual fixes don't work.

I can:

* deploy to the emulator

* run on the emulator

* debug on the emulator

* deploy on the phone

* run on the phone

I cannot:

* debug on the phone.

Attempts to start the debugger on the phone (F5 from VS) will recompile my app (if necessary), deploy it to the phone, and then raise the above error.

Yes, the "Build" and "Deploy" boxes are checked in Configuration Manager.
Yes, it has an appropriate SplashScreenImage.jpg
Yes, the phone is dev-unlocked, and pin-unlocked.

**Update 1:**

Unregistering and reregistering the device didn't help.

But the problem **is** device-specific -- it doesn't happen on a different phone.

If no other solution turns up, I'll probably reset the phone to factory original and start over.

**Update 2:**

I have two phones and two development systems. Three of the four combinations work great; it's only one phone on one dev system. Resetting the phone to factory condition didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did unregistering then re-registering the phone with the Registration Tool in the SDK fix it?

Comment: I get this all the time. I just keep trying to debug and it eventually works (normally after a couple of tries). That probably doesn't help you a whole lot, but I figured I'd post this anyway...

Comment: what happens if you uninstall the app on the phone, then deploy it again?

Comment: in certain cases i had to first start the Zune player and then VS2010 to make it work. Perhaps that does the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the WP Connect tool instead of using Zune?, I have had a few occasions where Zune does not see the phone properly or the device link registration was invalid (also try telling Zune to forget the particular device in the settings)

In any case using the WP connect tool (without Zune running) has usually worked for me in these cases.